# Como testar um link de Internet com retorno do HTML

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para testar alguns links de internet interpretando um retorno HTML.

Exemplo: Tenho 5 servidores com uma página de teste em HTML no inetpub de cada um, e tenho 3 links de internet e alguns DNS no-ip, gostaria de fazer uma página tipo a de consulta disponibilidade da NF-e, porém teria um botão que ao clicar exibiria quais links retornaram ok e quais retornaram erro e se possível o tempo gasto para o retorno. Abaixo um print do site da NF-e:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não podes fazer simplesmente com html, vais ter de usar javascript ou php.

Comment: Estou ciente que só com HTML não tem como, o que gostaria de saber e talvez não tenha ficado claro, é como fazer a requisição as páginas e como ler o retorno e com isso informar ao usuário que o serviço está ativo ou não.

Comment: tem... faça uma requisição por javascript e veja se retornou o código 200